# Why are there multiple enumerations for similar color space conversions in OpenCV Python V3.4.2?

Tags: python, opencv, colors

While converting an image from BGR to YCrCb colorspace there are two alternative enumerations in OpenCV:

```
img = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2YCrCb)
```

or

```
img = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2YCR_CB)
```

OpenCV also has two enumerations for BGR to CIE LAB color space conversion: `cv.COLOR_BGR2LAB` and `cv.COLOR_BGR2Lab`, BGR to CIE LUV color space conversion: `cv.COLOR_BGR2LUV` and `cv.COLOR_BGR2Luv`, etc. Are there any subtle differences between the results produced by the separate enumerations?

Comment: Good question about where those come from. However there's no difference, it's just two names for the same numerical value.

Comment: OK, [this](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/a11f9e196390dcf88466f6ae470ffd1f900bef85/modules/python/src2/gen2.py#L933-L935) is why. And [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/commit/c4c731c0aa79e3587a08b713e796c26c839455f5) is where it came from. Commit message explains that it's a backward compatibility thing.

Comment: @DanMašek Thank you very much for the clarification. I could not find any differences in visualization or in raw data either. Please make an answer so that I can accept it.